# How to connect my local SQL Server to google colab?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pyodbc

This is the error I get:

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

When trying to run this code:

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = (r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};r'SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;'r'DATABASE=AdventureWorks2014;'`r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'` 
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str) */  #mycode
```

Comment: The code works fine in jupyter notebook local

Comment: "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" is relatively old. Are you sure you don't have a newer version such as "OBDC Driver 17 for SQL Server" that's [currently available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)?